# Maven Shade Plugin does not include needed classes from dependancy

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, maven-shade-plugin

In a project, I use as a dependancy an artifact which is in the same groupId than this project.

The dependancy is well imported and used in my IDE, but when I compile the jar, no classes from the dependancy are copied inside the final jar. So I get exceptions at runtime...

Why ???

The dependancy POM head :

```
<groupId>com.example.things</groupId>
<artifactId>project-foo</artifactId>
```

My project POM head :

```
<groupId>com.example.things</groupId>
<artifactId>project-bar</artifactId>
```

My project POM section to declare dependancy :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.things</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-foo</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.345-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My project POM Maven Shade Section :

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
            <artifactSet>
                <includes>
                    <include>com.example.things:project-foo</include>
                </includes>
            </artifactSet>
            <filters>
                <filter>
                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>META-INF/*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </filter>
            </filters>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Thanks for helping, it seems I do something wrong...

Comment: `<scope>provided</scope>` means (with my words): not maven, but *user/admin/dev* has to care! (for the availability on classpath..at runtime) ..or: "it won't be packaged"(by maven)!

Comment: Detailed doc: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope

Comment: So please try `<scope>runtime</scope>`